# Get content of list of span elements with HTMLUnit and XPath

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

I want to get a list of values from an HTML document. I am using HTMLUnit.

There are many span elements with the class topic. I want to extract the content within the span tags:

```
<span class="topic">
  <a href="http://website.com/page/2342" class="id-24223 topic-link J_onClick topic-info-hover">Lean Startup</a>
 </span>
```

My code looks like this:

```
    List<?> topics = (List)page.getByXPath("//span[@class='topic']/text()");
```

However whenever I try to iterate over the list I get a `NoSuchElementException`. Can anyone see an obvious mistake? Also links to good tutorials would be appreciated.

Comment: could you add the line that the error comes with? Removing the text() from xpath, and using the HtmlElement.getTextContent() is a better and safer solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you'll always have an `<a>` then just add it to the XPath and then get the `text()` from the `a`.

If you don't really know if you always will have an `a` in there then I'd recommend to use the `.asText()` method that all `HtmlElement` and their descendants have.

So first get each of the spans:

```
List<?> topics = (List)page.getByXPath("//span[@class='topic']");
```

And then, in the loop, get the text inside each of the spans:

```
topic.asText();
```

Answer (score 0):

`text()` will only extract the text from that element, and that example you've given has no text component, only a child element.

Try this instead:

```
List<?> topics = (List)page.getByXPath("//span[@class='topic']");
```