# How to use getByXPath properly in HTMLUnit?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am not entirely sure on how getByXpath works

I already tried this [Get content of list of span elements with HTMLUnit and XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091091/get-content-of-list-of-span-elements-with-htmlunit-and-xpath?rq=1) solution but it still doesn't work.

This is part of the code that I have right now:

```
HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);
List<?> date = (List)page.getByXPath("//div[@class='list-box-comment']");
System.out.println(date.size());
for(int i =0 ; i<date.size();i++){
    System.out.println(date.get(i).asText());
}
```

It is said that I can't use .asText() for whatever reason.

What is the right way to get the inside of a tag that has a certain class?

This is the site I want to scrape (https://www.tokopedia.com/berkahcell2/promo-termurah-vr-virtual-reality-box-v-2-0-remote-bluetooth-gamepad/review?src=topads), the part that I want to take is the comment section below.

Comment: Please provide the url you use to make it possible to reproduce your problem

Comment: @RBRi added the url.

Comment: You use a `List<?> date`, so Java doesn't know what `date.get(i)` returns, so you cannot call `asText()` without an explicit cast to the expected type that defines the `asText()` method.